# significance of trap statement inside a trap function

Tags: bash

```
function signal_trap_action {
  exit_code=$?
  log "\"$0 $subcmd\" EXIT_CODE=$exit_code"
  trap "" $trap_signal_spec
}

trap_signal_spec="$(echo {0..64} | sed 's/ 9 \| 19 20 / /g')"
trap signal_trap_action $trap_signal_spec
```

The trap in the main script is calling function signal_trap_action, where another trpa is defined. What does this line `trap "" $trap_signal_spec` means ?

Comment: Nothing to do with your question but to define your list of signals you could: `trap_signal_spec=( {0..64} ); unset trap_signal_spec[{9,19,20}]` and then use `"${trap_signal_spec[@]}"` instead of `$trap_signal_spec`. This would also make it very easy to add or remove signals from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does this line trap "" $trap_signal_spec means ?

It means to ignore signals specified by trap_signal_spec.

Comment: In the context of the above, this line `trap "" $trap_signal_spec` can be removed, If it's ignoring signals ?

Comment: "can be removed" - it can, but this will change the behavior of the code. After receiving a signal, _then_ the next signal is ignored. If removing the line, the next signal will not be ignored, which looks like was not the intention of the writer.